# Bash variable assignment

Tags: bash, variables

I have a basic script to edit config files in ~/.config - it works with the `cd` lines, but that seems redundant:

```
dir=$HOME/.config/$1
if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then :
    else 
    cd "$dir" && 
    for file in * ; do
        case "$file" in
        conf | config | *.cfg | *rc)  $EDITOR "$file" ;;
        *)  :  ;;
        esac
    done
    cd - 1>/dev/null;
fi
```

Changing it to use the variable `"$dir"` fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
dir=$HOME/.config/$1
if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then :
    else 
    for file in "$dir" ; do
        case "$file" in
        conf | config | *.cfg | *rc)  $EDITOR "$file" ;;
        *)  :  ;;
        esac
    done;
fi
```

Comment: Why on earth do you write `if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then :; else cd "$dir" ...` instead of simply `if [ -d "$dir" ]; then cd "$dir" ...`?

Comment: @glenn thank you: ignorance. Pure and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use just "$dir" because that gives just a single item: the directory. You need $dir/*, but that includes the path as well, so you have to strip that off to compare just the file name:

```
...
for file in $dir/*; do
    filename=`basename $file`
    case $filename in
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked. Is there anything I could read up on to more fully understand this?

Comment: @Edouard: I'm afraid I can't really point you to a great resource. Most of what I know of shell scripting, I've picked up on the fly. I had to do a google search to find the "basename" command because I couldn't remember it :) Basically, the "for" iterates over all the files that come after "in". The $dir/* expands to a list of all the files that are in whatever directory "$dir" is. If $dir is /foo/bar, and that has a file named "baz" in it, then inside the loop, $file will have the value /foo/bar/baz. The `basename` command will strip off the path and give you "baz". Does that explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You're not globbing the files inside `$dir`, merely listing `$dir` itself. Try `$dir/*`.

Comment: Precisely! Beat me to it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your first version does a `*` on the directory, yielding a list of all the files in the directory.  Your second version just has one entry in the list --- the directory itself, not its contents.